# 'Object Library invalid or contains reference to object' error

Tags: vba, excel, activexobject

I had made an Excel macro using some ActiveX control buttons. It runs perfectly on my old PC. Some days back I purchased a new PC and when I compiled it reflect following error:-

> "Object Library invalid or contains references to objects definitions that could not be found."

Also when I run this macro in design mode through the ActiveX button, it creates a sample blank module by a new default name corresponding to that button.

I tried everything that is available on the web. I even removed .exd files, checked my .ocx files. etc.

Now I am clueless about what to do as same macro is running perfectly on my colleagues laptop and they also have same version of Excel even.

Screenshot of the error that I am getting when compiling the code.

[image: attached screenshot]

Comment: You're not giving us much to go on there - have a look in the `Tools ~ References...`menu.  Do any of the items in the list start with `MISSING`?

Comment: Nothing comes as missing there. Do I need to register the common active objects again? I don't know which .ocx file corresponds to them.

Comment: Can you run any other subs in that project?

Comment: Would it be the ocx calendar control?  I think there's as many variations of that as there are words in the English dictionary (ok, maybe a little less - one per version of Excel).

Comment: Well, it's hard to tell remotely but as a guess it's having an issue with that button active-x control. To confirm that, I would initially replace the Button control with a forms control and recompile it to see if corrects/gives you a different error. I had something similar to that a long time ago and it was an installation issue. Is reinstalling Office to test an option?

Comment: Try removing the activex control and replacing it with a Form button instead.

Comment: Would you attach a picture of the workbook references...

Comment: I am not able to run any of the subs in the project. When i click on activex button, it creates a blank module with default button name.@ Macro Man..

Comment: I haven't use any calendar control in my macro. @ Darren..